# Error while build project "uses unchecked or unsafe operations"

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, build, jframe

I don't know why this happens.

Error details
Note: `C:\Users\mcsentul\Documents\NetBeansProjects\HitungListrik\src\hitunglistrik\HitungListrik.java` uses unchecked or unsafe operations.

Note: Recompile with `-Xlint:unchecked` for details.

this is my code

```
public HitungListrik() {
    super("PEMBAYARAN REKENING LISTRIK");
    try {
        UIManager.setLookAndFeel(new NimbusLookAndFeel());
    } catch (UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
        Logger.getLogger(HitungListrik.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
    }

    Container konten = getContentPane();
    setVisible(true);

    setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    setSize(550, 500);

    konten.setBackground(Color.LIGHT_GRAY);

    konten.setLayout(null);
    // konten.pack();
    konten.addMouseListener(new MouseListener() {
        @Override
        public void mouseClicked(MouseEvent e) {
            Point mouse = e.getPoint();

            System.out.println("tambah" + mouse);
        }

        @Override
        public void mousePressed(MouseEvent e) {
            // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseReleased(MouseEvent e) {
            // throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseEntered(MouseEvent e) {
            //   throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }

        @Override
        public void mouseExited(MouseEvent e) {
            //   throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Not supported yet.");
        }
    });

    combob = new JComboBox();


    title = new JLabel("PEMBAYARAN REKENING LISTRIK");
    title.setBounds(100, 20, 400, 20);
    title.setForeground(Color.BLUE);
    title.setFont(new Font("Arial", Font.BOLD, 19));
    konten.add(title);

    for (int i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        combob.addItem(bulan[count++]);
        combob.setBounds(100, 55, 120, 30);
        t.setEditable(false);

    }
    konten.add(t);
    konten.add(combob);

    combob.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        @Override
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            t.setText((String) ((JComboBox) e.getSource()).getSelectedItem());
        }
    });

    lbulan = new JLabel("Bulan ");
    lbulan.setBounds(40, 55, 80, 30);
    lbulan.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    konten.add(lbulan);


    String msg;
    msg = "No image";
    ImageIcon image = new ImageIcon(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("image/pln.png"));
    lgbr = new JLabel(image);
    if (image != null) {

        lgbr.setIcon(image);
        lgbr.setText("");

    } else {
        lgbr.setText(msg);
        System.out.println(msg);
    }

    lgbr.setBounds(460, 5, 60, 50);
    lgbr.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    konten.add(lgbr);

    lbiayaperkwh = new JLabel("Biaya Per Kwh ");
    lbiayaperkwh.setBounds(240, 55, 120, 30);
    lbiayaperkwh.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    konten.add(lbiayaperkwh);





    tkwh = new JTextField();
    tkwh.setBounds(340, 55, 150, 30);
    tkwh.setEditable(false);
    konten.add(tkwh);

    lbulan = new JLabel("Daya ");
    lbulan.setBounds(40, 100, 80, 30);
    lbulan.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    konten.add(lbulan);

    v450 = new JCheckBox("450 Volt Ampere", false);
    konten.add(v450).setBounds(100, 110, 120, 20);

    v450.addItemListener(new mainAction());
    //    jenisantrian = new JCheckBoxGroup();
    v900 = new JCheckBox("900 Volt Ampere", false);
    konten.add(v900).setBounds(100, 140, 120, 20);
    v900.addItemListener(new mainAction());

    v1350 = new JCheckBox("1350 Volt Ampere", false);
    konten.add(v1350).setBounds(100, 170, 120, 20);
    v1350.addItemListener(new mainAction());

    labodemen = new JLabel("Abodemen");
    // labodemen.setIcon(imgThisImg);
    labodemen.setBounds(40, 220, 120, 30);
    labodemen.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    konten.add(labodemen);


    tabodemen = new JTextField();
    tabodemen.setBounds(120, 220, 100, 30);
    tabodemen.setEditable(false);
    konten.add(tabodemen);

    bhitung = new JButton("Hitung");
    bhitung.setBounds(40, 300, 100, 30);
    bhitung.addActionListener(new HitungListrik.mainAction());
    konten.add(bhitung);


    blagi = new JButton("Lagi");
    blagi.setBounds(150, 300, 100, 30);
    blagi.addActionListener(new HitungListrik.mainAction());
    konten.add(blagi);


    /// 
    ljumlah = new JLabel("Jumlah");
    ljumlah.setBounds(240, 100, 120, 30);
    ljumlah.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    konten.add(ljumlah);


    tjumlah = new JTextField();
    tjumlah.setBounds(340, 100, 150, 30);
    tjumlah.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            char c = e.getKeyChar();
            if (!((c >= '0') && (c <= '9')
                    || (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE)
                    || (c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE))) {
                getToolkit().beep();
                e.consume();
            }
        }
    });

    konten.add(tjumlah);

    ltagihan = new JLabel("Tagihan");
    ltagihan.setBounds(240, 140, 120, 30);
    ltagihan.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    konten.add(ltagihan);

    ttagihan = new JTextField();
    ttagihan.setBounds(340, 140, 150, 30);
    ttagihan.setEditable(false);
    konten.add(ttagihan);

    lpajak = new JLabel("Pajak 10%");
    lpajak.setBounds(240, 180, 120, 30);
    lpajak.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    konten.add(lpajak);

    tpajak = new JTextField();
    tpajak.setBounds(340, 180, 150, 30);
    tpajak.setEditable(false);
    konten.add(tpajak);

    ltotal = new JLabel("Total");
    ltotal.setBounds(240, 220, 120, 30);
    ltotal.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    konten.add(ltotal);
    ttotal = new JTextField();
    ttotal.setBounds(340, 220, 150, 30);
    ttotal.setEditable(false);
    konten.add(ttotal);


    luang = new JLabel("Uang cash");
    luang.setBounds(300, 300, 80, 30);
    luang.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    konten.add(luang);
    tuang = new JTextField();
    tuang.setBounds(390, 300, 110, 30);
    tuang.addActionListener(new HitungListrik.mainAction());
    tuang.addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
        @Override
        public void keyTyped(KeyEvent e) {
            char c = e.getKeyChar();
            if (!((c >= '0') && (c <= '9')
                    || (c == KeyEvent.VK_BACK_SPACE)
                    || (c == KeyEvent.VK_DELETE))) {
                getToolkit().beep();
                e.consume();
            }
        }
    });
    konten.add(tuang);


    lkembali = new JLabel("Uang kembali");
    lkembali.setBounds(300, 340, 100, 30);
    lkembali.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 15));
    konten.add(lkembali);

    tkembali = new JTextField();
    tkembali.setBounds(390, 340, 110, 30);
    tkembali.setEditable(false);
    konten.add(tkembali);


    bhapus = new JButton("Hapus");
    bhapus.setBounds(70, 400, 100, 40);
    bhapus.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 17));
    bhapus.addActionListener(new HitungListrik.mainAction());
    konten.add(bhapus);


    bkeluar = new JButton("Keluar");
    bkeluar.setBounds(330, 400, 100, 40);
    bkeluar.setFont(new Font("Serif", Font.PLAIN, 17));
    bkeluar.addActionListener(new HitungListrik.mainAction());
    konten.add(bkeluar);




}

class mainAction implements ItemListener, ActionListener {

    @Override
    public void itemStateChanged(ItemEvent ev) {

        if (ev.getStateChange() == ItemEvent.SELECTED) {
            //  cb1.setEnabled(false);
        }
        Object pilihan = ev.getItemSelectable();

        if (pilihan == v450) {
            tabodemen.setText("25000");
            tkwh.setText("250");
            daya = "450 Volt Ampere";
            v900.setEnabled(false);
            v1350.setEnabled(false);
            if (v450.isSelected() == false) {
                daya = "";
                tabodemen.setText("");
                tkwh.setText("");
                v900.setEnabled(true);
                v1350.setEnabled(true);
            }
        } else if (pilihan == v900) {
            tabodemen.setText("35000");
            daya = "900 Volt Ampere";
            tkwh.setText("350");
            v450.setEnabled(false);
            v1350.setEnabled(false);
            if (v900.isSelected() == false) {
                daya = "";
                tabodemen.setText("");
                tkwh.setText("");
                v450.setEnabled(true);
                v1350.setEnabled(true);
            }
        } else if (pilihan == v1350) {
            tabodemen.setText("45000");
            daya = "1350 Volt Ampere";
            tkwh.setText("450");
            v450.setEnabled(false);
            v900.setEnabled(false);
            if (v1350.isSelected() == false) {
                daya = "";
                tabodemen.setText("");
                tkwh.setText("");
                v900.setEnabled(true);
                v450.setEnabled(true);
            }
        }


    }

    @Override
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {

        if (e.getSource() == bhitung) {
            if ("".equals(t.getText().trim())) {
                String peringatan = "Anda belum memilih bulan";
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, peringatan);
            } else if ("".equals(tjumlah.getText().trim())) {
                String peringatan = "Isi jumlah penggunaan KWH";
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, peringatan);
            } else {

                System.out.println("=============================================");
                System.out.println("   Tagihan bulan " + t.getText().trim());
                System.out.println("=============================================");

                System.out.println(t.getText().trim());
                String sjumlah = tjumlah.getText().trim();
                int ijumlah = Integer.parseInt(sjumlah);
                String skwh = tkwh.getText().trim();
                int ikwh = Integer.parseInt(skwh);
                int tagihan = ijumlah * ikwh;
                double pajak = tagihan * 0.1;
                ttagihan.setText(String.valueOf(tagihan));
                tpajak.setText(String.valueOf(pajak));
                total = tagihan + pajak;

                bayar = tkembali.getText().trim();
                NumberFormat f = NumberFormat.getInstance();
                f.setGroupingUsed(false);
                String r = f.format(total);
                ttotal.setText(String.valueOf(r));

                System.out.println("Jumlah Daya   : " + daya);
                System.out.println("Biaya Per KWH : " + ikwh);
                System.out.println("Jumlah KWH    : " + ijumlah);
                System.out.println("Pajak         : " + pajak);
                System.out.println("Total yang harus dibayar   : " + total);



            }


        }


        if (e.getSource() == blagi) {
            v900.setEnabled(true);
            v1350.setEnabled(true);
            v450.setEnabled(true);
            v450.setSelected(false);
            v900.setSelected(false);
            v1350.setSelected(false);
            combob.setSelectedIndex(0);
            tkwh.setText("");
            ttotal.setText("");
            tpajak.setText("");
            tjumlah.setText("");
            tabodemen.setText("");
            ttagihan.setText("");

        }
        if (e.getSource() == bhapus) {
            v900.setEnabled(true);
            v1350.setEnabled(true);
            v450.setEnabled(true);
            v450.setSelected(false);
            v900.setSelected(false);
            v1350.setSelected(false);
            combob.setSelectedIndex(0);
            tkwh.setText("");
            ttotal.setText("");
            tpajak.setText("");
            tjumlah.setText("");
            tuang.setText("");
            tkembali.setText("");

            tabodemen.setText("");
            ttagihan.setText("");
        }
        if (e.getSource() == bkeluar) {


            int selectedOption = JOptionPane.showConfirmDialog(null,
                    "Anda yakin mau keluar?",
                    "Choose",
                    JOptionPane.YES_NO_OPTION);
            if (selectedOption == JOptionPane.YES_OPTION) {
                System.exit(0);
            }
            // System.out.println("tambah");
        }
        if (e.getSource() == tuang) {
            if ("".equals(tuang.getText().trim())) {
                String peringatan = "Anda belum mengisi jumlah uang yang diberikan User";
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, peringatan);
            } else {
                String uang = tuang.getText().trim();
                int iuang = Integer.parseInt(uang);
                double kembali = iuang - total;
                if ((total - 0) <= 0) {
                    String peringatan = "Belum ada data";
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, peringatan);
                } else if (iuang < total) {
                    String peringatan = "Uang yang anda masukkan lebih kecil dari Total yang harus dibayarkan";
                    JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, peringatan);
                } else {
                    bayar = uang;
                    System.out.println("Bayar         : " + bayar);
                    System.out.println("Kembali       : " + kembali);
                    Date date = new Date();
                    System.out.println("=============================================");
                    System.out.println("+  " + date + "    +");
                    System.out.println("=============================================");
                    tkembali.setText(String.valueOf(kembali));
                }
            }
        }

    }
}
}

class test {//main

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Date date = new Date();
    System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
    System.out.println("+  Log " + date + "    +");
    System.out.println("+++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++++");
    HitungListrik a = new HitungListrik();//create frame
    a.setResizable(false);//agar tidak bisa di perbesar

    Dimension dim = Toolkit.getDefaultToolkit().getScreenSize();
    int x = (dim.width - a.getSize().width) / 2;
    int y = (dim.height - a.getSize().height) / 2;
    a.setLocation(x, y);

}//end method
}//end class
```

Comment: Your question is too broad; please edit your question to include an [mcve](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that isolates a single, typical, unsafe operation.

Comment: Read the docs - [`JComboBox`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JComboBox.html) is a generic class. You have a raw type. Note that this is the least of your worries - you application doesn't run on the EDT but on the main thread. This violates Swing's threading policy.

Comment: yes thanks @Boris, i done it by add <String> into  private JComboBox<String> combob; and combob = new JComboBox<>();

but i cannot open the jar file directly, i click it but didnot show anything